# Select data in one table but.

Tags: sql

I want to select all records from table bookstore, following this condition:

> and the condition is it should not exist  in another table,borrowed,
>   by comparing shelf number which exist as columns in both tables

I don't know what i am suppose to provide to be answered correctly apart from what i just given, so if anything is needed, i will provide.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bookstore 
WHERE bookstore.shelf does not exist in borrowed.shelf_number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`SELECT * FROM bookstore WHERE bookstore.shelf NOT IN (SELECT shelf FROM borrowed)`

We make use of the `NOT IN (..)` syntax which allows us to grab the `shelf` from that table.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from bookstore where shelf not in (select shelf_number from borrowed)`
What is your DB engine? I can do this in `sqlserver`.